# Rails gem localized_country_select undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rubymine

I'm trying to use the gem referred in the tittle to put a dropdown list with all the countries in a user creation form. I've written gem 'localized_country_select', '>= 0.9.9' in the GemFile and ran bundle install. After that, i updated the user form view with the following code:

```
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :country %><br>
*******<%= localized_country_select(:user, :country, [], {:include_blank => 'Please choose...'}) %>*******
</div>
```

When I try to access the new user page it appears me the following error:

undefined method `map' for "translation missing: en.countries":String

Well, thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need locale en.rb in your config/locale. Else it wont work. Copy this to your config/locale.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlitwiniuk/localized_country_select/master/locale/en.rb

Now restart your server and try.